# How do I control the size at which strings get allocated in the stack rather than the heap?

Tags: c++, string, visual-c++, stl

Is there a control in the string library that I can change so that larger strings are allocated in the stack? I want to experiment the performance difference in changing the allocation strategy. My hypothesis is that allowing for larger strings to be allocated in stack may increase the performance.

Comment: Your text is asking the opposite of your title.  Either way though, the answer is no.  We might be able to help if you explain what the problem is that you're trying to solve.

Comment: Also note that if `std::string` uses SSO is implementation defined. In fact MSVC implementation does, but GCC's does reference counting (COW). **You should rely on Standard behaviour, not implementation specific things.** Also your intention is missleading, since you expect performance gains tunning the string: The implementers would do some profillings before selecting a stack buffer size, is not decided rolling dice...

Comment: @mark I altered the title and the description. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your question assumes that smaller strings are already allocated on the stack. I doubt that standard specifies such behavior (at least I cannot find it there) so even if some implementation of C++ standard library use such technique it would be implementation specific. And asking such question without specifying particular version of library does not have much sense.

Answer (score 0):

It should be fairly obvious that changing the short string optimization threshold will alter the ABI of `std::string`, since it changes the footprint of string objects.  For that reason, if you were to be able to change the SSO threshold then you would need either to make the threshold part of the type (in which case it wouldn't be `std::string`) or to ensure that every object file is compiled with the same threshold setting.

Indeed, MSVC doesn't even provide a setting for whether to enable the SSO at all; [STL explains here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9a59970d-c7bf-4ed5-8267-e482c4e461a7/stl-string-is-a-memory-hog?forum=vclanguage) that the Microsoft library team are wary of the potential downsides:

> Being able to enable or disable this feature could certainly be useful - however, it can also be a source of problems.  The _SECURE_SCL and _HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING options change the representations of STL containers (what it does to std:: string is more subtle and confusing), so all translation units that are linked into a single binary must be compiled with the same settings, and binaries that pass STL containers and iterators around must be compiled with the same settings.  This already causes problems for customers, which a _SMALL_STRING_OPTIMIZATION switch would exacerbate.
>
> That's not to say that we won't ever implement such a switch - only that doing so wouldn't be free of negative impacts.

As mentioned there, [STLPort](http://www.stlport.org/) does allow you to enable or disable the SSO via the preprocessor flag `_STLP_USE_SHORT_STRING_OPTIM`. I'm not aware of any STL implementation that allows you to tune the SSO threshold, either through a preprocessor define or a template parameter, but it should be relatively straightforward to do this yourself by modifying an existing STL-compatible `string`; there's plenty to choose from (STLPort, BSL, libc++ in addition to your vendor's STL).

For example, in BSL the SSO buffer is [calculated from a minimum required size](https://github.com/bloomberg/bde/blob/master/groups/bsl/bslstl/bslstl_string.h#L807):

```
    SHORT_BUFFER_MIN_BYTES  = 20, // minimum required size of the short
                                  // string buffer in bytes
```

You would need to change this either to a preprocessor define or to a template parameter passed through from an extra parameter to `basic_string`.